# Power wires too short, what to do?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, junction-box

When I see a short wire, what can I do? There are close to ceiling junction boxes on top of the outlets where the wires come from, should I pull the short wire back into them and splice them with new long wires to extend them? Like with a twister on or wago connector?

Or should I try to rewire and replace the entire length of the wire coming from the apartments breaker? I'm tempted to try this because in one of the junction boxes I see black oily grime like char on the shielding of same wires, which leads me to think are somepoint something exploded in there.

[image: green short wire pictured here]

Comment: Are they multiconductor cables, or in conduit?

Comment: What country is this located ?

Comment: I'm wanting to know if these wires are in conduit because the advice is completely different if they are.   The reason I think they're in conduit is the unusual wire colors, very odd for cable but very typical of conduit.   In fact it might make this rather easy.

Comment: It's an outlet, I wouldn't worry about colors they random, electricians here follow no rules.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a push-in connectors like https://www.toolstation.com/shop/p29476
Just add extension wires.

Comment: Are those like wago connectors? What's the difference? When I ask electrician he tell me they just twis them together with pliers and electric tape, but I can't do that, I will ruin the cable.

Comment: Don't listen to the electrician that told you to twist them together and tape them. @Vald is spot on.  You could also try a wire nut pigtail like the Ideal #30-170 just make sure you get the correct color and wire nut size.

Comment: I think those in-sure connectors are technically rated for stranded wire, but after a few experiments, decided I didn't like them (just my opinion... I'm not a regulatory body...). Wago makes a similar connector with a cam lock that's apt to be better.

Comment: The WAGO 222  lever connectors are inexpensive and do not deform the ends of the conductors. An "electrician" who told you to twist wires together and tape is someone you should never trust again.

Answer (score -1):

> Don’t let short electrical wires cramp your DIY project. Splice in
>   extra wire in a few seconds using easy push-in connectors.
>
> Electricians should leave at least six inches of wire in wall boxes,
>   which will provide enough length to install a new switch or outlet.
>   When they don’t, it makes stripping wires and getting solid
>   connections a difficult task.
>
> Wire nuts are effective for connecting wires, but sometimes the wire
>   is to short to get a proper connection. Using the push-in connectors,
>   you simply push the bare end of a wire into the connector and a spring
>   clip will hold it in place. Insert the bare end of your jumper wire
>   and you’ve got an instant connection.
>
> Watch the video at the link below for a basic demonstration of how to
>   lengthen your wires.

From: [Lengthen Electrical wires that are too short](https://lifehacker.com/lengthen-electrical-wires-that-are-too-short-by-splicin-1739577987)

I have a degree in Associates in Scienece in Electrical Engineering Technology from St petersburg College. Dec 1998
Also did Some Electrical worl under a Licensed Electrical Contractor
 I would recomend a 20 Amp Residential Grade Self Grounding Tamper Resistant Duplex Outlet, White
[Leviton
20 Amp Residential Grade Self Grounding Tamper Resistant Duplex Outlet, White](https://lifehacker.com/lengthen-electrical-wires-that-are-too-short-by-splicin-1739577987)
[Home Depot Self grounding outlet](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-Residential-Grade-Self-Grounding-Tamper-Resistant-Duplex-Outlet-White-R52-T5820-0WS/202078776)

Comment: Although I hate Push in connectors and think anyone that uses them is a hack there is no reason to give this answer a down vote without a reason why. So I up voted it! I will usually add a new box closer to the panel and provide some extra wire in the new box and at least code required length in the original box in the U.S. Back stab outlets are limited to to 15 amp circuits or 14 gauge wire. Wago stabs are listed for 20 amp circuits so why the down vote?  They are legal and I don't use them other than florescents and believe they are a hack for real power.  Fess up if you down vote.

Comment: Please review the SE policy on referencing other works to avoid being flagged for plagiarism: https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/referencing